# What is a good, accurate, free online textual source of the Quran in Arabic?

Tags: quran, reference-request

I am in the process of doing textual analysis on the Quran using software, but I am not sure I am finding a reliable, quality, accurate version of the Quran (in Arabic) *which my computer can parse*. What are the most accurate / standard versions of the Quran in Arabic which are in plain text format (or JSON, or spreadsheet, etc., just not as an image, PDF, or app)? I need it in some sort of plain text format which is easy for my computer to parse, so using something that is distributed over 114 wiki pages won't be the easiest to work with (and Arabic PDFs are usually not possible to read with a computer).

Some background. Searching the web you quickly find the "[Quran code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quran_code)", which says there are 2,698 occurrences of the word [Allah](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87) in the Quran. Many other people say this too. But so far I have found that there are different numbers of the word ٱلله in the Quran (I removed diacritics too), depending on which version I grabbed/found.

- [This version](https://github.com/risan/quran-json/blob/main/data/quran.json) has 2153 usages of the word.
- [This version](https://github.com/quranacademy/quran-text/blob/master/quran-uthmani.txt) has 2265 usages of the word.

Neither of those are even close to the number 2698. And given the ~100 word disparity even between these two "versions" is unnerving to say the least. It means at least one of them is wrong. So I am looking for a good copy which I can work with on my computer.

Comment: I would first advise you to not put much credibility into any "Quran code." And second, have you compared what occurrences the two seem to disagree on using your software

Comment: Thirdly, have you checked whether they include usages of لله (lillah) as well? Fourthly, have you checked whether they include Bismillah in each Surah? Fifthly, have you considered that those who espouse this code 19 deny some verses of the Quran as being part of it? That could change the count as well

Comment: I can arrive at 2698 using my software by 1) not including لله, d 2) adding one for each Bismillah in the beginning of every Surah except Tawbah, and 3) discluding the verses that Rashad Khalifah denied as being part of the Quran.

Comment: The second source includes the basmala and the first doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you should first check the truth and origin of the 2689 of Khalifa. I could imagine that he counted the   الله 's in اللهم and other words.